# How to revert / undo my last two pushes (commit and revert) in github?

Tags: github

I got a Github repository from client where there is no code.
I cloned this repository and pasted my code folder to this repository and pushed the code to git.
But now I need to revert back my commit. For this I did the following steps:

```
git revert xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(commit)

git add .

git commit -a -m "reverted back"

git push origin master
```

After this I went to my github page, there I find project folder with app/views, config, db, log, public, tmp folders where revert is not properly done.

How to undo my last 2 commits (both commit and revert) and get back to the main repository as it is?

Please help me, I am worried.

Comment: You add back your changes after you revert the commit

Comment: So are you saying you want to undo the revert commit?

Comment: I want to undo the revert commit and the push commit (that is done before revert) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is just to hard reset to commit preceding the bad one:

```
git reset --hard xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx^
git push -f origin <your-branch-name>
```

There `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is your sha, that you reverted in the first time. 
Note the `^` before `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. It means that you reset to the commit *before* `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Or you can specify exact hash to reset to, i.e.

```
git reset --hard A
```

Before resetting your branch is looking like:

```
A -> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -> B(bad)
```

After `git reset --hard xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx^`

```
A
```

`git push -f origin <your-branch-name>` pushes your  local changes made on the previous step to the Github server

**Be careful with force pushing though, because you force your local repository state on the server. So you lose server state forever**

Comment: Here I need to reset last 2 commits. Can we use `git reset --hard xxxxxxxxxx` two times and then `git push -f origin maste`r (as I pushed to master) ?

Comment: @venkat, reset is absolute, not relative. Also see my edit

Comment: After I reset I can use `git push -f origin master` right?

Comment: Yes. It will move your local repository state to github

Comment: It worked, as I am the only developer `git push -f origin master` didn't affected me :)